# how to filter records on change of dropdown in mvc Razor

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have requirement like i have a list of vendors which are binded on the page load and i have dropdown also which is used to filter that vendors record on change of dropdown.

My view:

```
<div class="half-left">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.subCatObj.SubCategory_Id, Model.GetAllSubCategory, "--Select--", new { @id = "subCategory", @class = "contactField" })
        </div>


        @foreach (var vendor in Model.GetAllVendors)
        {
              @vendor.VendorCompanyName  
        }
```

my question is how to filter the records on change of dropdown..please help

Comment: Use Jquery and ajax to populate the vendor drop down on the filtering drop down's change event. Or, store all your venders in a javascript array on the client side and write a javascript function which does your filtering logic to populate the vender drop down from the array of vendors, filtered using your filtering logic

Comment: i want to use it using razor,is there any solution using Razor

Comment: With your setup as it is, you could do your filtering logic in a javascript function and add a class to each option that shouldn't be in the drop down list which sets the display attribute to none, this way you can keep your razor code, but still accomplish the filtering of the drop down list.

Comment: Thanks Ryan..can you share a example of it so that i could get it easily..i am new to programming

Comment: Do you know how to use CSS? Are you using JQuery in your webpage?

Comment: Yes,I know. i am using jquery in my project

Comment: I offered a solution below as an answer, if it helps you to get this working, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

IN Your CSS:

```
//CSS class to use on your option elements to make their display property none
.hiddenOption{
   display:none;
}
```

If using an external javascript file which you are importing into your View, or a script tag in your view, with JQuery, use the document.ready to attach change event to your subCategory dropdown:

```
//Use document.ready in JQuery to add change handler to drop down
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subCategory').on('change', function(){
         //Call your filtering function here
         FilterVenders();
    });
});

//Declare and define a function for doing the filtering in your external
//script or in your script tag of View
function FilterVenders(){
    //As I don't know what kind of logic you use to filter, you need to
    //Work on this portion
    const subCategoryValue = $('#subCategory').val();
    const subCategoryText = $('#subCategory option:selected').text();

    //Loop all the options in your drop down list and apply the class
    //which makes their display as none (hide the options)
    $('#subCategory > option').each(function(){
         //If the option is not to be displayed, add the class
         //This is where you need to step in and provide the filtering logic
         if(condition){
            //Check if option is already hidden, if not add the class to hide it
             if(!$(this).hasClass('hiddenOption')){
                 $(this).addClass('hiddenOption');
             }
          }else{
             //Check if option is hidden, if so, remove class to unhide it
             if($(this).hasClass('hiddenOption')){
                 $(this).removeClass('hiddenOption');
             } 
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan..got it

Comment: @sumit.spider Ok. If you are happy with my provided answer, please mark it as the accepted answer.